# Is it true that two people who love each other but cannot be together will meet in Jannat?

Tags: jannah

I love someone and she loves me too but there are problems, due to which we cannot have a relationship for a long time, but she and I decided that we will both meet with each other in Jannat.
It is true that those people who love each other will meet in Jannat?

Answer (score 4):

Briefly speaking, in regards to your question as you’ asked

> “it is true that those person who love each other will meet in jannat
>   ? kindly tell me that we will meet with each other ?”

The answer can be positive, yeah. Allah is the most compassionate, the most merciful. Actually He will give us whatever we want in the Jannah and every wishes can be done in all probability.

But another important point is that you should pay attention that God will convey you to her in case of endeavoring avoid committing sin. I mean beside other deeds, you should forget each other in order to destroy all fields of the sin which can be related between you two respected persons. Afterwards you can be hopeful to reach what you desire.

As an extra related issue which could be interesting for you is that, as far as I can remember, once I heard that (almost) according to a hadith “in the heaven, except the houries, men can order to be with their wives who will be edited in better faces, bodies, …” Consequently you can meet each other even in very better faces… (Note: Solely the problem of you is that you are non-mahram here and must forget each other in order not to committing any kind of sin …

And finally, I would forget her if I were you. Because I'm certain that Allah will give us many better items in the jannah (if we go to the jannah, In-Shaa-Allah)

Comment: Your welcome. Good luck.

Comment: but if the intensity of love is much more, like cannot live a second in peace(pain in heart un-controllable, weeping, even after two years). Then what should do.
Also I read that only the wifes will meet with their husband so how can we meet in jannat. Is there still any hope or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you stop the relationship with her and stop contacting with her.

> Ibn 'Umar (Radhiallaahu Ta'ala anhu) narrated:
>
> > "'Umar delivered a Khutbah to us at Al-Jabiyah. He said: 'O you people! Indeed I have stood among you as the Messenger of Allah(s.a.w) stood among us, and he said: "I order you (to stick to) my Companions, then those who come after them, then those who come after them. Then lying will spread until a man will take an oath when no oath was sought from him, and a witness will testify when his testimony was not sought. **`Behold! A man is not alone with a woman but the third of them is Ash-Shaitan.`** Adhere to the Jama'ah, beware of separation, for indeed Ash-Shaitan is with one, and he is further away from two. Whoever wants the best place in Paradise, then let him stick to the Jama'ah. Whoever rejoices with his good deeds and grieves over his evil deeds, then that is the believer among you.'"
> >
> > > Jami` at-Tirmidhi 2165

Pray 5 times a day to acquire piety.

It'll certainly enable you to get inner peace.

And Allaah Ta'ala promises to give rewards to those who are pious.

> **`Dr. Ghali's Translation`**
>   **Wicked women (are) for wicked men, and wicked men (are) for wicked women; and good women (are) for good men, and good men (are) for good women. Those are (declared) quit of whatever they (i.e., of what the wicked ones say) say; they will have forgiveness and an honorable provision.**
>
> **`Muhsin Khan's Translation`**
>   **Bad statements are for bad people (or bad women for bad men) and bad people for bad statements (or bad men for bad women). Good statements are for good people (or good women for good men) and good people for good statements (or good men for good women), such (good people) are innocent of (each and every) bad statement which they say, for them is Forgiveness, and Rizqun Karim (generous provision i.e.Paradise).**
>
> > Surat An-Noor: 26

**`link:`** [Surat An-Noor: 26](http://legacy.quran.com/24/26)

And, be assured that Allaah Ta'ala will fill up your every wish in Jannah.

So, make your preparation for Jannah.

And Allaah Ta'ala knows best.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all

Answer (score 0):

First, In jannah you will have your full choice of whatever you want.

However in case of this question, you must know that the love you wanted in duniya must also agree to come with you in jannah at same time. So tell your love to agree to come with at that time and follow all rule of Allah in duniya.

Also remember whether your current partner after marriage is bad or good to you, he or she will be good for you in jannah because there is no evil thinking in jannah. But still you will have your choices to choose what you want.

Also in duniya you must follow Hadith and all orders of Allah so Allah will give Jannah and it is different things then what you want in jannah.
In duniya sometime we can not get what we want but those we can get in jannah.

In many answer it is normally suggested that to forget your love. But actual intention behind it to restrict those activities which will take you in hell.  So dont do such haram things,  in duniya we have certain limits but in jannah we won't have such limits.

Hope this answer will satisfy you. So be happy with present situation and in the end you will have what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Same situation is with me and her. We can't get married here in this world but we have planned to meet in jannah. Can some one please give me answer in YES OR NO?

Comment: no body answered with definite yes or no because there may not be having any source to backup this. Only thing mentioned is that those who enter paradise will have whatever they wish for. The downvotes for your answer maybe because this is not an answer but a comment.