# Reunion in Paradise

Tags: jannah, love

If a man's wife dies, they'll be reunited in paradise isA (if they succeeded in this world) even if the man married a woman after her. So far so good.

Now, what if the man dies before his wife and he really loved her and she loved him, but she married a man after him. Would they also be reunited? If so, then how?

(Please provide reference, sunni point of view is encouraged, but shi'i is accepted)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relationship between her and me](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27591/relationship-between-her-and-me)

Comment: Ummm, no. It's different. The one you're referring to is just talking about "2 lovers" who were not married. I was asking about 2 married couple who were already united in this life through a legal marriage contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://islamqa.info/en/8068) has an answer to your question.

My personal opinion, and I could be wrong, that the woman can choose her husband in Paradise if both of her husbands have been admitted to Paradise by the mercy of Allah (SWT). My opinion is based on this verse in Surat Qaf:

> لهم ما يشاءون فيها ولدينا مزيد
>
> They will have in it whatever they wish, and with Us there are things
>   even more than that.

If the woman wishes her first husband, she, due to the grace and the mercy of Allah (SWT), will be with him.

Again, I could be wrong, and indeed Allah (SWT) knows the best.