# In jannat can we marry someone we love and who was not our spouse

Tags: quran, jannah

Assalamu Alaikum.

the question that i need to ask is that, if someone cannot marry who he/she may love and is not possible due to some reasons and have left everything on Allah.... Is it possible that they get married in jannah? As in jannah there won't be any jealousy and this worldly life will not be more than just a blink of an eye.
Because this world is just a test and the actual result is in jannah and whatever you wish for you will get it there.

please answer my question

Comment: Check out this [question](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29645/reunion-in-paradise)