# "Anything" in paradise? My love?

Tags: jannah, love, pain

Assalamualaikum
I want to know that literally everything is possible in jannah?
I'm in the deepest of love with a woman 10 years older than me. We wanted to marry each other but due to worldly restrictions and parents and families, she has been married to someone else.
If you think that our relation was haraam, its wrong.
Im sure that it was not haram, but due to some personal reservations I can't reveal all the details here.
As far as my love for her is concerned, she is my only happiness in this world, I pray everyday for her with tears.... and I respect her so much.
I want to know that if we are blessed with jannah, will we be able to live together as spouses ? Because nothing is impossible for Allah, and He knows the purity of my love.
Please do not give discouraging answers, I'm already in serious pain. :'(

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I don't see this as a dupe... the difference being that in this question the woman is married to someone else whereas in the other that part is not clear. I see it as a major detail, which can affect the nature of the answer provided.

Comment: "Please do not give discouraging answers, I'm already in serious pain. :'(" - Does that mean what you're looking for is encouragement instead of an answer about what Islamic doctrine has to say about this?

Comment: @Zaid: Maybe that's relevant (the OP can clarify).  It's a fairly common question though, e.g., [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36633/17163), [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30333/17163), [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33574/17163).

Comment: Before thinking about jannah, why not think about divorce ?