# I want both of us to be together in Jannah

Tags: hereafter

I'm a Hindu born guy who has converted into Islam. And the girl I love is also a Hindu by birth and has converted into Islam. Infact I developed interest in the religion after she came into my life. We both have kept this as secret in our families. We both love each other and want to get married but the problem here is that, she's a higher caste *Thakur* girl and I'm a lower cast guy, by birth. So we can't live together in this *Duniya* and if we try, then her family would kill both of us and harm my family too as they a powerful people. The thing is that I can't give anyone else her place and can't image to live with some other woman. So can I stay unmarried and control my natural desires. Is it Haram in Islam to do this? I want us to be together in *Jannah*.
Please answer if you can.

Comment: Don't vandalize the post. Go to your [profile](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/37630/yash-vardhan-sagar) then Settings and from there delete your account, then your name will be removed and the question will remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I could really say would be to make dua. But, this question is pretty common among this forum. This post should help you:

[Is it true that two people who love each other but cannot be together will meet in Jannat?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27591/is-it-true-that-two-people-who-love-each-other-but-cannot-be-together-will-meet)

Comment: I can't find anything related to staying unmarried. Please answer.